# Invalid cast exception when reading result from SQLDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My stored procedure:

```
    @UserName nvarchar(64),

    AS

    BEGIN
    SELECT MPU.UserName, SUM(TS.Monday)as Monday //TS.Monday contains float value
    FROM dbo.MapTask MT JOIN dbo.MapPU MPU
    ON MPU.ID = MT.MPUID
    JOIN dbo.TimeSheet TS
    ON MT.TMSID = TS.ID
    WHERE MT.StartDate = @StartDate_int and MPU.UserName = @UserName
    GROUP BY MPU.UserName
    END
```

In my C# code

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            float monday = (float)reader["Monday"]; // Invalid cast exception
        }
```

Can somebody tell me what I did wrong ? Thank you.

Comment: You can try Convert.ToFloat(reader["Monday"].ToString());

Comment: @Jethro: That's a pretty horrible way of doing it though. When a conversion fails, replacing it with *two* conversions (to and from string) is generally *not* a good idea.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, that does make sense, plus Convert.ToFloat doesn't exist. Need to be more carefull. If Convert.ToFloat did exist would it be better to do this then. Convert.ToFloat(reader["Monday"]); ??

Comment: @Jethro: It would be better to call reader.GetFloat IMO. Give control of the conversion to the reader itself.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

My guess is that the value is being returned as a boxed `double` instead of `float`. When you unbox the type has to be *exactly* right. So assuming I'm right and it's not `decimal` or something like that, you could use:

```
float monday = (float) (double) reader["Monday"];
```

and it would work. That's pretty ugly though. If you use [`SqlDataReader.GetFloat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getfloat.aspx) it should get it right *if* it's genuinely a single-precision value, and it's clearer (IMO) what's going on.

On the other hand, your data could *actually* be coming back from the database as a `double`, in which case you should (IMO) use:

```
float monday = (float) reader.GetDouble(column);
```

As an aside, are you sure that `float` is actually the most appropriate type here in the first place? Often `decimal` is more appropriate...

Comment: If the datatype in SQL Server is "float", then calling SqlDataReader.GetFloat will unfortunately throw an error, because the naming conventions are completely incompatible.  An SQL "float" is actually a double-precision value and therefore maps to a .NET double.  An SQL "real" is the single-precision that maps to a .NET float.  .NET's names are internally inconsistent, instead of choosing "double" and "single" as keywords, it mixes "float" in, whereas in SQL it's "float" and "real" with no reference to double or single precision.

Answer (score 15):

A sql float is a .NET Double, see on the  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx).
Try casting to a double.

Comment: You can try casting to double and then to float, that is what I do.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The cast exception occurs because SQL server uses "float" and "real" to refer to double and single-precision values respectively. I'd imagine it's a common mistake to try to call SqlDataReader.GetFloat on an SQL "float" field, because that would make sense, but alas, you must call SqlDataReader.GetDouble. And if you meant to store a single-precision value, it's back to the database to change the type from "float" to "real". They should have just stuck to "float32", "float64", "int32", int64" instead of all this "tiny" "small" "big" "real" "single" "double" nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar issue and ended up doing this:

```
if (!oDR.IsDBNull(0))
    Rating = (float)oDR.GetSqlDecimal(0).Value;
```

oDR.GetFloat(0) was returning and invalid cast exception when accessing the result of a *SELECT AVG(...)*.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
float monday = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Monday"]);
```

would be a nice approach.  I am trying to find a solution for over an hour and it fails here. now it works fine.