# Sql to Gridview in android

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using this code

```
 SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name,Price from Inventory", con);

    SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        adapter.Add((string)sqlReader["Name"]);
       adapter.Add((string)sqlReader["Price"]);


    }
    sqlReader.Close();
```

I get error Specified cast is not valid.Column Price it is stored as float

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid cast exception when reading result from SQLDataReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146088/invalid-cast-exception-when-reading-result-from-sqldatareader)

Comment: You tried to change the cast of the `Price` field from `adapter.Add((string)sqlReader["Price"]);` line?

Comment: No how will i do that?

Comment: You can try to change it for `adapter.Add((float)sqlReader["Price"]);` or `adapter.Add(sqlReader["Price"]);`

Comment: First your first example i get the same error. for second cannot convert object to string